# Can't see my own question in the hot list

Tags: support, bug, top-questions

Just posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41359232/3240681) on the SO. But can't find it in the [homepage](https://stackoverflow.com/), i.e. in the *Top Questions* list.

Why?

More newest and oldest questions from another users are displayed in that list:

> [image: asked]

> [image: list]

For now question has an answer, but I still can't see it in the homepage (even in private mode). Maybe some problem with a title?

Also, question has 3 votes for close. Could this be a reason to hide question from homepage?

Comment: From what i know homepage list is generated based on your favorite tags do you have one of the tags in your question as favorite tag?

Comment: It also could mean that a lot of questions have been asked since your question

Comment: @Abhishekgurjar As I know top question list contains ALL question with recent activities. Also I have a some of question tags in my fav tags.

Comment: @Doc page contains both: more newest and more older posts than my own. I.e. my question should be anywhere in the middle. But doesn't.

Comment: @alexolut ah yes, now I see now - that is indeed a bit odd

Comment: @rene I did. Already said in the answer body `"even in private mode"`.

Answer (score 2):

> As I know top question list contains ALL question with recent activities.

Not as far as I know. You are just shown a subset of posts that matches your current profile best. This is only on SO as far as I know where the number of posts is so high that they can't show all new posts, it just wouldn't make sense.

This [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/) shows some more information how the page is calculated, but it doesn't tell about the capping on Stack Overflow.