# Incorrect error message when trying to delete comment

Tags: bug, comments, error-message

Just tried to delete [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288933/cant-see-my-own-question-in-the-hot-list#comment937916_288933) and got error:

> [image: voting]

Seems "voting" should be replaced with "deleting".

Comment: That probably goes through the same endpoint that also handles *voting*. If it needs to be reworded maybe make it *An error occurred during the handling of whatever you were throwing at us but we gave up on you*. Or something more unfriendly if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deletion is done by voting, so the text is accurate enough. This is the case even when it takes only one vote, such as when self-deleting a post or when done by a moderator's binding delete vote.

One could argue that the message is still counterintuitive because most people expect an error message about deleting to mention deleting, not voting. One could equally argue though that it reinforces the little-appreciated fact that all delete attempts are done via a delete vote.

Answer (score 2):

If @rene is correct with their comment:

> That probably goes through the same endpoint that also handles voting.

then there are two solutions. One is that SE changes how the process gets handled where voting and deletion on or of a comment respectively are separate and we can have two different pop-ups as you suggested. A second solution makes the text a bit more broad:

> An error occurred while processing your request

or

> An error occurred while executing your request